# Validate a webpage against its doctype (dtd) within a Canoo Webtest step using a Groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, xsd, webtest, canoo-webtest

How can I validate a webpage against its doctype (dtd) within a Canoo Webtest step with Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I know the answer. But as it took me a while to get it working, I thought I'd share my solution. It's a webtest macro. You can also only use the sequential if you like...

```
<macrodef name="verifySchema" description="Validate the current document against its schema">
<sequential>
    <groovy description="validate schema" >
        import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
        import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser
        import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

        import java.io.InputStreamReader


        import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler
        import org.xml.sax.InputSource
        import org.xml.sax.SAXException
        import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
        import org.xml.sax.XMLReader

        class MyHandler implements org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler {
            void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                println 'WARNING: ' + e.getMessage()
            }

            void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                println 'ERROR: ' + e.getMessage()
                throw e
            }

            void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                println 'FATAL: ' + e.getMessage()
                throw e
            }
        }


            def factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
            factory.setValidating(true)
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true)

            def parser = factory.newSAXParser()
            def reader = parser.getXMLReader()
            reader.setErrorHandler(new MyHandler())
            def response = step.context.currentResponse.webResponse
            reader.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(response.contentAsStream,"UTF-8")))
    </groovy>
</sequential>
```

If you want to fail your test on warnings too, add a throw statement to the handler accordingly.